# Adding Uniswap interface to a ERC20 token smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

I just started learning Solidity, as browse through various smart contracts for tokens listen on Uniswap, I notice that most of them use IUniswapV2Factory and IUniswapV2Router02 and a small amount don't (resulting in less code and less gas fee in order to deploy). I was wondering if there are any pros/cons to including this interface as I couldn't find any information online as to what they concretely do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some tokens create their a token pair and register it with uniswap. They implement some form of integration with the token pair, like charging a percentage for fees or dynamically adjusting the token supply.

Other tokens do not have an integration with uniswap so they don't have to import those files.